# possibility of attaching video in plotGoogleMaps in R

Tags: javascript, html, r, google-maps

I am succesfully able to plot many of my data points in googlemap.

But then I wanted to do below thing:

1. add an image as a background to my plotGooglemap markers
2. add an youtube embeded video in infowindow in my plotGooglemap markers

No. 2 is high priority, No. 1 if possible then ok.
At the moment I got some manual solution for video embedding.
My R code for generating that html file using plotGoogleMaps is as below:

```
require(plotGoogleMaps)  
NucData <- read.csv("./locationdata.csv")
NucData$Location <- gsub(",",":", NucData$Location)
NucData$latitude <- as.numeric(levels(NucData$latitude))[as.integer(NucData$latitude)]
NucData$longitude <- as.numeric(levels(NucData$longitude))[as.integer(NucData$longitude)]
coordinates(NucData)<-~longitude+latitude # convert to SPDF
proj4string(NucData) <- CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ')
myplot<-plotGoogleMaps(NucData,filename='MyMap.html', zcol='location.Name'
                  , draggableMarker=FALSE, colPalette=c('#FF0000', '#FFA500',                '#65ed12'),
                   )
```

This was generating the map nicely, then after some research I have manually changed the generated html file "infowindow.setContent" section as below:

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "", disableAutoPan:false, maxWidth :320, pixelOffset :null  }); 
google.maps.event.addListener(markersNucData7557[0] ,"click",function(event){ 

infowindow.setContent('<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Video in Info Window</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<iframe width="300" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uV3R4lCc9YI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>'); 

 infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
infowindow.open(map,markersNucData7557[0] )});
```

It works nicely...I can embed the YouTube video for that particular marker.
But as I have many data points and corresponding many video links, manually changing html file code one by one is not an option. Is there any way that I can do it through R code..I tried to utilize the InfoWindowControl option in plotGoogleMaps function below way but failed.

```
m<-plotGoogleMaps(NucData,filename='MyMap.html', zcol='location.Name'
                  , draggableMarker=FALSE, colPalette=c('#FF0000', '#FFA500', '#65ed12'),
    InfoWindowControl=list(map=map, event="click",position="event.latLng",
                           disableAutoPan=FALSE, maxWidth=330,
                           content="('<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Video in Info Window</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<iframe width="300" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uV3R4lCc9YI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>')")
```

Is there any other kind of R package based approach or if at all not possible then any easy Java side code would be great.

Comment: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39339464/5977215) to your other question