# easiest way in R or Python to add image/video in map plot marker click popup/infowindow

Tags: javascript, python, html, r, google-maps

I have many different (lat,long data) points of world associated with unique place names and corresponding each point specific image or video data. Now I want to create an html file where if user click on each point they can see that specific image or video in the pop-up/infowindow. Previously I have successfully used html files with my shiny web application.

Target examples links are as below but they are all in Java:

1. [custom image in marker](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html)
2. [custom video in marker](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Xk6Uu/)

   ```
   <script>
   // This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
   // When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

   function initialize() {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
     var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 4,
       center: myLatlng
     };

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

     var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
     '<div id="siteNotice">'+
     '</div>'+
     '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Video in Info Window</h1>'+
     '<div id="bodyContent">'+
     '<iframe width="640" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/a8UOzBUZxCw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
     '</div>'+
     '</div>';

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: contentString
     });

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatlng,
     map: map,
     title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });
   }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
   ```
3. [streetview image in marker](http://jsfiddle.net/sST8z/)

   ```
   var map;
     var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

     function initialize() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
       street = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("street"), { 

       position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.72982797782924, -73.98622512817383),
       zoomControl: false,
       enableCloseButton: false,
       addressControl: false,
       panControl: false,
           linksControl: false
     });


     var infow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: document.getElementById("street") });
     var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.72982797782924, -73.98622512817383);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map, visible: true });

     infow.open(map, marker);
     map.setCenter(myLatLng);

     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   ```

First I have tried with plotGoogleMaps, there I have to manually change the   generated html file javascript section code for each marker so it is becoming a lot of manual work. So alternatively Is there any way to achieve the same in " leaflet " or " rleafmap " R package or any other combination of R-based package ?

I am more from R less from Python, is there any easy solution exists in Python at least to generate that html page. I just want to build that html file so that I can use in shiny web framework.

Finally,
I tried below but blank page is coming up.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <style type="text/css">  
 html { height: 100% ; font-size: small} 
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
 #map_canvas {min-height: 100%;height:auto; } 
 #cBoxes {position:absolute;right:5px; top:50px; background:white}
</style> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.18"> </script>  

 <script language="javascript"> 

 USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView(); 
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
      this.bounds_ = bounds;
      this.image_ = image;
      this.map_ = map;
      this.div_ = null;
      this.setMap(map); }
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
      var div = document.createElement("DIV");
      div.style.border = "none";
      div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
      div.style.position = "absolute";
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = "100%";
      img.style.height = "100%";
      div.appendChild(img);
      this.div_ = div;
      this.div_.style.opacity = 0.7;
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);}
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
        var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
        var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
        var div = this.div_;
        div.style.left = sw.x + "px";
        div.style.top = ne.y + "px";
        div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + "px";
        div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + "px";} 
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() { 
 this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);} 
USGSOverlay.prototype.hide = function() { if (this.div_) { this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";} } 
USGSOverlay.prototype.show = function() {if (this.div_) {  this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";}} 
       USGSOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() { 
 if (this.div_) { 
  if (this.div_.style.visibility == "hidden") {  
   this.show(); 
  } else { 
  this.hide(); } } } 
 USGSOverlay.prototype.toggleDOM = function() {
          if (this.getMap()) {
            this.setMap(null);
          } else {
            this.setMap(this.map_);}}
 function setOpacR(Raster,textname) { 
  opac=0.01*parseInt(document.getElementById(textname).value) 
    Raster.div_.style.opacity= opac } 


// bounds of the desired area
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(28.70, -127.50),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.90)
);
var boundLimits = {
  maxLat : allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
  maxLng : allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
  minLat : allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
  minLng : allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
};

var images = [{url:"http://images.com/rome.png", position:new google.maps.LatLng(27.7220605,91.8254337)},
              url:"http://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/A/AP/APPILCHEI-TRENDILCH29488C3956E0D_29487/0x1920/70/0.jpg", position:new google.maps.LatLng(15.5967635,73.8928171)},
              url:"http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/sari/x/z/c/11036-roop-kashish-400x400-imadq4f6n3fh6kht.jpeg", position:new google.maps.LatLng(30.9740215,77.1982669)},
              url:"http://stat.homeshop18.com/homeshop18/images/productImages/958/de-marca-faux-chiffon-saree-yellow-240X336-5X7-240fabfeb551480eba911e34d90b4a20.jpg", position:new google.maps.LatLng(12.303889,76.654444)}];

for(var i=0l i<images.length; i++){
  var m = new google.maps.Marker({position:images[i].position});
  m.infow = new google.maps.InfoWindow("HTML using image template, splicing in the URL using '+''s");
  google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function(){
    this.infow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
    this.infow.open(map);
  });
}

</script> 
 </body>  
  </html>
```

Comment: What data do you already have? Is it literally just image/video URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a list of URLs for images and/or videos, it would literally be as simple as iterating through them in JavaScript, and assembling the HTML in JavaScript. It would be unnecessarily complicated to make a ton of HTML pages, and have to call them.

```
var images = [{url:"http://images.com/rome.png", position:new google.maps.LatLng()}, ....];
var videos = [{url:"http://videos.com/borneo.wav", position:new google.maps.LatLng()}, ....];
for(var i=0l i<images.length; i++){
  var m = new google.maps.Marker({position:images[i].position});
  m.infow = new google.maps.InfoWindow("HTML using image template, splicing in the URL using '+''s");
  google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function(){
    this.infow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
    this.infow.open(map);
  });
}
//same for videos
```

Instead of copy and paste, this will be efficient, readable, and scalable.

Therefore, as far as I understand your problem, you do not need Python or R to solve it.

Comment: how to access local images ? will it work like {url:"D:/R Projects/rome.png", position: new google.maps....

Comment: Instead of `http://`, use `file:///`. But if you are making a web application, you should try to upload your images online if possible. It will make your application more reachable.

Comment: I have updated my question with new code as per your suggestion but page is coming blank...please help..your idea would help me.

Comment: ok i will accept your answer and put a new question with the javascript code....but please help me

Comment: Please remove your email. I also sent you a message.

Answer (score 1):

In R you can do this using my package [googleway](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) which has a Google Maps widget. You can customise marker info windows with normal `html`.

To use Google Maps you'll also need a valid Google Maps API key

```
library(googleway)

#key <- "your_api_key_here"

df <- data.frame(lat = -37.817714,
                 lon = 144.967260,
                 info = '<div id="bodyContent"><iframe width="640" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/a8UOzBUZxCw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>')

google_map(key = key, height = 600, search_box = T) %>%
    add_markers(data = df, info_window = "info")
```

[image]